# How to reiterate the set of python functions

Tags: python, excel, hex, ascii

In Excel, I have set of strings in each column: like:

Column1- Column6= STR10110.90.9

Column7-Column12=STR10220.90.9

And goes on..

Now for the column 1-6 , I have written python code to read each cell from Excel & do hex conversion  as:

C1- STR1--> string into hex --> 53545231

C2- 0--> into hex --> 30

C3- 1 --> float into hex --> 0000803f

C4-1 --> float into hex --> 0000803f

C5-0.9 --> float into hex --> 6666663f

C6- 0.9 --> float into hex -->6666663f

Now the problem is , once I reach the column 7, I need to check if the cell is empty or not. If data is available , I need to reiterate the same set of hex conversion for C7-C12 & again I need to check C13 for data, if so reiterate the same set of hex conversion function.

1. How to check if the cell is empty or not.
2. And how to reiterate the same set of functions. Like again goto top/ loop . Any help
   Thanks in advance.

Comment: of course it is possible, try to solve it yourself, SO is not here to do the work for you, as of now you did not demonstrate any real effort of trying

Comment: Hey Derte, i didnt ask anyone either you to do work for me. Dont make any IRRELEVANT comments. I have just asked is it possible ? indirectly i meant direct conversion or do i need to change to binary before hex ?..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For counting the rows, used the xlrd (nrows) and
For the reiterate , converted the rows into list & used next iterate function to loop within created list.